# I am working in linux and have tot extract archives that were already in an archive. Could anyone explain how to extract this while using loops?

Tags: linux, loops, unix, terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -xvf assignment_UA_InleidingProgrammeren_Huistaak1-HelloWorld_2019-11-11.tgz
a=$(echo assignment_UA_InleidingProgrammeren_Huistaak1-HelloWorld_2019-11-11.tgz | cut -b 15-35)
b=$(echo assignment_UA_InleidingProgrammeren_Huistaak1-HelloWorld_2019-11-11.tgz | cut -b 37-56)
#cutcommand van geeksforgeeks.org
mkdir -p "$a"/"$b"
mv assignment_UA_InleidingProgrammeren_Huistaak1-HelloWorld_2019-11-11/*.tgz InleidingProgrammeren/Huistaak1-HelloWorld
rmdir assignment_UA_InleidingProgrammeren_Huistaak1-HelloWorld_2019-11-11

for x in InleidingProgrammeren/Huistaak1-HelloWorld
```

I have already extracted the first archive but i have to extract tthe tgz archives that are in this archive without using hardcode.

I have tried using different loops but it doesn't work and i don't know if i am using them correctly.

Comment: Show us the exact format of your archive of archives.  Provide a [mcve].  How many "levels" of archives do you have?  Only the one?

Comment: i have the first archive "assignment_UA_InleidingProgrammeren_Huistaak1-HelloWorld_2019-11-11.tgz" and insid of that one i have 6 archives of the same format

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- you have an archive, a.tgz, containing some files.
- you have an archive, b.tgz, containing some files.
- both a.tgz and b.tgz are themselves contained in another archive, top.tgz.
- both a.tgz and b.tgz do not exist outside top.tgz when the script starts.

> t.tgz
>     - a.tgz
>          - some files
>     - b.tgz
>          - some files

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tar -xzf top.tgz
rm -f top.tgz
for F in *.tgz
do
    tar -xzf "$F"
    rm -f "$F"
done
```

- Extract the top archive first.
- Delete that top archive (or move it somewhere else) so the `for F in *.tgz` does not process it again.
- Then loop on the new archives and extract them.
- Final result, all files from a.tgz and b.tgz are available.